# Can I use hyperledger fabric for real-time application?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Is it reasonable to use blockchain for realtime services like task scheduling?

Fabric architecture is suitable for my problem, but I'm not sure metrics and overheads are reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, hyperledger fabric has a moderate throughput of transactions. Should be able to get at least 3k transactions/second. Version 2.0 is capable of 20k/sec according to some researchers who made some modifications to the ordering service. Research here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.00910.pdf

Comment: I've done a prototype with the composer and, it takes 1 or 2 seconds for each transaction to commit. (with only two nodes)
am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Composer is not currently under active development by the Hyperledger Project and doesn’t support all the features of fabric. I would try with just the sdk

Comment: Where are you getting those numbers from, we haven't seen anywhere near that transaction throughput in our 1.4 release stream? 1k is a much more reasonable number. One of our project Maintainers for Fabric published this performance analysis https://www.ibm.com/blogs/blockchain/2019/04/does-hyperledger-fabric-perform-at-scale/

Comment: There are causes for commits taken multiple seconds. There are timeouts for how long we wait to commit a block, in the event more transactions come in that we can commit with that block. I recommend looking at the documentation for all of the settings you can tweak in Fabric.

Comment: Here is just one source but I originally found in research article https://www.google.com/amp/s/cointelegraph.com/news/upgraded-hyperledger-fabric-sees-7-fold-increase-in-transaction-speed/amp

Comment: @lindluni and in personal use it typical takes under 10 milliseconds per request \n this is the original paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.00910.pdf

Comment: That paper has never been implemented unfortunately. They are working to build an implementation of it, but as of yet, it remains just research.

Comment: Thanks I’ll edit my answer but it can get to 3k out of the box as stated in the research the current max is around 3k TPS.